# How to size wxWindows properly

Tags: c++, layout, wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets C++ program made in Code::blocks. On the desktop PC it looks fine, but not on windows tablets.

[image]

The following picture is what it should look like (at least all of the text should be visible):
[image: Window on desktop PC]

I already tried several ways, at the moment my code looks like this:

```
TrackDialog::TrackDialog(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id,const wxPoint& pos,
                         const wxSize& size)
{
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer4;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer5;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer2;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer1;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer3;
    wxBoxSizer* pPanelSizer;

    Create(parent, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxSTAY_ON_TOP|wxSUNKEN_BORDER, _T("wxID_ANY"));
    SetMinSize(wxSize(500,400));
    Panel1 = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL1, wxPoint(184,136), wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    pPanelSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    BoxSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    StaticSelectText = new wxStaticText(Panel1, ID_STATICTEXT1, _("Select a *.xml file."), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT1"));
    BoxSizer1->Add(StaticSelectText, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    pPanelSizer->Add(BoxSizer1, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    XmlFilePickerCtrl = new wxFilePickerCtrl(Panel1, ID_FILEPICKERCTRL1, _T("./resources/"), wxEmptyString, _T("*.xml"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFLP_FILE_MUST_EXIST|wxFLP_OPEN|wxFLP_USE_TEXTCTRL, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_FILEPICKERCTRL1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(XmlFilePickerCtrl, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    pPanelSizer->Add(BoxSizer2, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer3 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    StaticNumberText = new wxStaticText(Panel1, ID_STATICTEXT2, _("Tracknumber"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT2"));
    StaticNumberText->Disable();
    BoxSizer3->Add(StaticNumberText, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    pPanelSizer->Add(BoxSizer3, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer4 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    ChoiceTrack = new wxChoice(Panel1, ID_CHOICE1, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, 0, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_CHOICE1"));
    ChoiceTrack->Disable();
    BoxSizer4->Add(ChoiceTrack, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    pPanelSizer->Add(BoxSizer4, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer5 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    ButtonOk = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON1, _("OK"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    BoxSizer5->Add(ButtonOk, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    pPanelSizer->Add(BoxSizer5, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Panel1->SetSizer(pPanelSizer);
    pPanelSizer->Fit(Panel1);
    pPanelSizer->SetSizeHints(Panel1);
    Center();

    Connect(ID_FILEPICKERCTRL1,wxEVT_COMMAND_FILEPICKER_CHANGED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&TrackDialog::OnXmlFilePickerCtrlFileChanged);
    Connect(ID_BUTTON1,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&TrackDialog::OnButtonOkClick);
    //*)
    Connect(ID_CHOICE1,wxEVT_COMMAND_CHOICE_SELECTED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&TrackDialog::OnChoiceTrackSelect1);
    SetSize(DoGetBestClientSize());
    Fit();
}
```

Additionally, another dialog is way too big:
[image: Other dialog]
with this code:

```
PortsDialog::PortsDialog(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id,const wxPoint& pos,
                         const wxSize& size)
{
    //(*Initialize(PortsDialog)
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer4;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer5;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer2;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer1;
    wxBoxSizer* BoxSizer3;

    Create(parent, id, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE, _T("id"));
    SetClientSize(wxDefaultSize);
    Move(wxDefaultPosition);
    Panel1 = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL1, wxPoint(200,320), wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    BoxSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    BoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    StaticComText = new wxStaticText(Panel1, ID_STATICTEXT1, _("COM Ports"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, _T("ID_STATICTEXT1"));
    BoxSizer2->Add(StaticComText, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(BoxSizer2, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer3 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    TextCtrlVibroTacPort = new wxTextCtrl(Panel1, ID_TEXTCTRL1, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TEXTCTRL1"));
    BoxSizer3->Add(TextCtrlVibroTacPort, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    ButtonVibroTacPort = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON1, _("Set VibroTac Port"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
    BoxSizer3->Add(ButtonVibroTacPort, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(BoxSizer3, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer4 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    TextCtrlGnssPort = new wxTextCtrl(Panel1, ID_TEXTCTRL2, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TEXTCTRL2"));
    BoxSizer4->Add(TextCtrlGnssPort, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    ButtonGnssPort = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON2, _("Set GNSS Port"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON2"));
    BoxSizer4->Add(ButtonGnssPort, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(BoxSizer4, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer5 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    ButtonClose = new wxButton(Panel1, ID_BUTTON3, _("Close"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON3"));
    BoxSizer5->Add(ButtonClose, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    BoxSizer1->Add(BoxSizer5, 0, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    Panel1->SetSizer(BoxSizer1);
    BoxSizer1->Fit(Panel1);
    BoxSizer1->SetSizeHints(Panel1);

    Connect(ID_TEXTCTRL1,wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER,(wxObjectEventFunction)&PortsDialog::OnButtonVibroTacPortClick);
    Connect(ID_BUTTON1,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&PortsDialog::OnButtonVibroTacPortClick);
    Connect(ID_TEXTCTRL2,wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_ENTER,(wxObjectEventFunction)&PortsDialog::OnButtonGnssPortClick);
    Connect(ID_BUTTON2,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&PortsDialog::OnButtonGnssPortClick);
    Connect(ID_BUTTON3,wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,(wxObjectEventFunction)&PortsDialog::OnButtonCloseClick);
    //*)
    SetSize(DoGetBestClientSize());
    Fit();
}
```

I've seen many different methods to set the size, but until now I could not figure out a way that sets the size so that everything looks fine. 
Thank you for your help.

---

Edit: 
`SetSizerAndFit(BoxSizer1);` with the PortsDialog as Tibo suggested leads to the dialog being empty:

[image: Empty PortsDialog]

With `SetSizerAndFit(pPanelSizer);` in TrackDialog, it looks fine on start, but if I reload the text half of it is out of the window again and the program crashes if the window is closed... This is so confusing.

Concerning the version: I have Windows 10 Pro 64-bit version on all of my devices (tablet and PC) and I use wxWidgets v3.0.2 and Code::Blocks v13.12 (with GCC compiler following C++11 ISO)

Comment: @AHue, What OS do you have on the tablet? Which version of the library do you have? Did you try the layout sample?

Comment: Try calling `SetSizerAndFit` with your outermost sizer as argument and don't fiddle with the best size manually. Does this help?

Comment: @Tibo this does not work (see question) :(

Comment: @Igor what layout sample?... You mean the example from wxWidgets?

Comment: It looks to me that the default font size is too large.  Experiment with using a smaller font. e.g. SetFont( wxFont( 10,  wxDEFAULT, wxNORMAL, wxNORMAL ));

Comment: @AHue, it is a sample that is provided with the wxWidgets in the samples directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what this question is about, there seem to be several completely unrelated things here and I'd advise closing/deleting this one and asking each of them in separate new submissions.

But to try to answer the first question, the text is not fully visible because there is not enough space for it on the tablet. It won't wrap on its own, you need to use a control with support for wrapping or call `Wrap()` yourself on `wxStaticText` manually.

Comment: All right, I will follow your advice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096324/size-wxdialogs-so-all-of-the-text-is-inside-the-dialog is the new question. For the `Wrap()` part, then I need to get the width of the text somehow, don't I?...